# Add items to a recycler view?

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

So i;m try to implement a method in which when a button is clicked a new line or item is added to the recyclerview. I've read up a good bit about this and i just cant get my head around it. Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Here my adapter I believe this is where you write most of the code to add items to a recyclerview:

```
     public class DazAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DazAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
List<Information> data = Collections.emptyList();
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Context context;

public DazAdapter(Context context, List<Information> data) {
    this.context = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.data = data;
}

public void addData(Information newModelData, int position) {
    data.add(position, newModelData);
    notifyItemInserted(position);
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Information current = data.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(current.title);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView title;
    ImageView icon;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listText);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: add more items to the recyclerview with the touch of a button. eg add another line

Comment: But I don't get it. You have the code in place. All you have to do is call the method `addData` in your adapter with the proper `newModelData` argument in the proper position. So in your `onClickListener` just do something like `adapter.addData(new Information(), 1)`.

Comment: But then how can i change the text inside these new items?

Comment: What do you mean? You're `onBindViewHolder` is already taking care of that.

Comment: When ive created a new row with the button there is no text in it i wish to put text in the new rows that ive created

Comment: The information object has a title that you have to set.

Answer (score 1):

did you try calling [notifyDataSetChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) instead of *notifyItemInserted* on your addData method?

In my case, i used it to load my data from a [Loader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Loader.html), but i think it should work when you add a single item.

```
 public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<Data>> loader, List<Data> data) {
    this.mAdapter.setDatas(data);
    this.mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: you can check [this blog](http://thedeveloperworldisyours.com/android/add-item-recyclerview/#sthash.GaUpPP9f.dpbs) and [this example](https://github.com/thedeveloperworldisyours/FullRecycleView)